# How can I delete specific cookies and DOM in firefox automatically

Tags: firefox, cookie

I want to delete cookies and DOM storage from a specific site every few hours. It could be done by script (cron job) or from within firefox. Bash script preferred.

I only have cookie controller installed and have to delete the cookies/DOM manually.